# Building async with setTimeout like a promise with setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

On https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function they say that writing

```
async function foo() {
   return 1
}
```

is the same as writing

```
function foo() {
   return Promise.resolve(1)
}
```

So that means that if we want to 'transform' a promise into an async function, we have to replace `resolve(promise_result)` with `return promise_result`.

But when I try to use `setTimeout` with `async` it doesn't work:

```
const test1 = async () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            return 5;
        },
        2000,
    )
}
const test2 = () => new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(
            () => resolve(25),
            1000
        )
    }
)

const execute = async () => {
    const result = await test1();
    console.log(result); // undefined
}

execute();
```

If I use `await` on `test2` it works but it doesn't work on `test1`. Why is that ? Is `async/await` only meant to deal with pending promises without using `.then` or can I use `async` with `return result` instead of using `Promise` with `resolve` ?

Comment: Your original transformation only applies if you're returning from the main function. It doesn't work with callback functions.

Comment: The return value of the `setTimeout()` callback function is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its undefined because `test1` does not return anything back. take a closer look you return it in the anonymous function back

```
const test1 = async () => { // <--- this function returns nothing back. Nothing means "undefined"
    setTimeout(
        () => {       // <---- you return it here back in your anonymous  function witch makes no sense
            return 5;
        },
        2000,
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I now understand why I get undefined back. But how do I make a function using ```async```, not Promises, that uses ```setTimeout``` and returns something in the end ?

Comment: @David well i guess you cant. using `new Promise` is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

That's a fun one.
The problem here is that

```
const test1 = async () => {
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            return 5;
        },
        2000,
    )
}
```

test1 is an async function, BUT `setTimeout` is not.

`setTimeout` will just schedule whatever you pass it and return its timeoutID immediately.
In such a case, you'd really need to handle the Promise code *manually*.